# Efficient implementation of "category" tree? (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, categories, categorization

If I have a category tree where there is an undetermined level of subcategories, is it possible to get the entire tree of categories in one query (without any loops)?

This is a possible scenario:

```
 category_id  parent_id   Name
0           null        Home
1           null        Auto
2           0           Living Room
3           2           Couches
4           2           TV
5           4           Home Theatre
6           5           Cables
```

If you notice, Cables lineage is such that:
Home > Living Room > TV > Home Theatre > Cables

Right now, I get the parent category of the current category and keep looping until I get to the parent category that has a null parent category.  I know this part has been asked before. However, I'm wondering is there a better way to structure this table so that I don't have to run X amount of queries (or subqueries)?  I considered for instance adding a 4th column called parents or something that would have the entire lineage in a comma separated list (such that in this case parents would be: `5,4,2,0`. However this seemed tacky and inefficient (and easy to break).  Is there a better mechanism available?

Comment: Yes, there are a better structures than simple trees to model hierarchical data in databases. Have a look at e.g. [nested sets](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) or [closure tables](https://coderwall.com/p/lixing/closure-tables-for-browsing-trees-in-sql). Closure tables are similar to what you have in mind at the end.

Comment: I second the suggestion for closure tables. http://amzn.to/2gfNBc5 provides a good description of various approaches, including closure tables, to solving this problem.

Comment: I found this really useful when I was doing something similar: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: Tyvm. Never heard of a "closure table" before. Reading the articles now.